# Install RocketRaid 644L Raid Controller driver on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, raid

I bought a RocketRaid 644L and get stuck at driver installation.

```
uname -a
Linux hb38-backup 3.2.0-41.generic #66-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.2

lspci
RAID bus controller: HighPoint Technologies, Inc. Device 0645 (rev 01)
```

I down load the driver from [driver list](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_rr600-download.htm), I choose [this one](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/BIOS_Driver/RR64xL/Linux/130722/Binary/Ubuntu/rr64xl-ubuntu-12.10-x86_64-v1.3.13.0326.tgz).
I just simply type the install commend and reboot the server.

```
cd driver_folder
sudo sh install
```

But when I reboot the server, I the driver actually is not installed correctly, and can't load the disks.
But the BIOS can detect those disks, so I think the problem comes from the driver. Does anyone use this kind of Raid controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @dobey 's suggestion. I just solved this problem and share my solution here if you are facing the same problem.

1. Download the source code [here](http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_rr600-download.htm), go to the bottom of the webpage, click the download link for proper type of chip and server OS.
2. Extract the package `RR64xl_Linux_Src_v1.3.9_15_03_07.tar.gz` (just my case)
3. Install kernel build tools (gcc, binutils, make, etc.)
4. For Linux kernel 2.6 and 3.*, make sure there's corresponded kernel source files under folder `/lib/modules/'uname -r'/build`.
5. go to the extracted folder ***rr64xl-linux-src-v1.3.9***. Directly compile the driver source code by running `make`
6. If you are going to compile the source code for other machines, refer to the command `make CROSS_COMPILE=... ARCH=... KERNELDIR=...`
7. install the driver by `sudo make install`
8. install for a specific kernel, using `make install KERNELDIR=/usr/src/linux-X.X`. `make install` command will copy the driver module to the directory `/lib/modules/'uname -r'/kernel/drivers/scsi`, and update the `initrd file` if it contains an old version driver.
9. After the driver is installed, it can be loaded manually by `modprobe rr640l` (the driver version is just my case)
10. The driver will work immediately, no need to reboot the system.

Answer (score 0):

That driver appears to be for 12.10 only, and likely won't work on the older kernel in 12.04.

You will need to download the source and recompile it for your kernel.

Comment: Genius, I just solved the problem using your method! great thanks, also I want to post my solution below.